# Multiple hosts in [lb] of OKD 3.11 Ansible Inventory

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, openshift-origin, okd

I am planning to install "MULTIPLE MASTERS USING NATIVE HA WITH CO-LOCATED CLUSTERED ETCD" and no external load balance, So i got to know i have to enable Native HA by providing following section in inventory file

```
# Specify load balancer host
[lb]
lb.example.com
```

Can we provide multiple masters entries here? if not then what would happen if above mentioned node goes down?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More then one [lb] host isn't usefull. For every [lb] host will be executed [openshift_loadbalancer](https://github.com/openshift/openshift-ansible/tree/release-3.11/roles/openshift_loadbalancer) role without any IP-sharing etc.

According to [Load Balancing For HA Master Infrastructure](https://github.com/redhat-cop/openshift-playbooks/blob/master/playbooks/installation/load_balancing.adoc):

> Out of the box, the OpenShift has the ability to install an HAProxy instance on a host you designate as a lightweight load balancer between masters in Native HA mode. However, this only creates another single point of failure. It is much preferred to integrate an enterprise load balancer (LB) such as an F5 Big-IP™ or a Citrix Netscaler™ appliance. This integration does add some complexity to the install process. We attempt to explain those options below.

So if you want HA API Server Load Balancer you have to configure advanced balancing scheme as external LB by yourself according to [Load Balancing For HA Master Infrastructure](https://github.com/redhat-cop/openshift-playbooks/blob/master/playbooks/installation/load_balancing.adoc)

According to [High Availability Masters](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/architecture/infrastructure_components/kubernetes_infrastructure.html#high-availability-masters):

> If the API Server load balancer is not available, nodes cannot report their status, all their pods are marked dead, and the pods' endpoints are removed from the service